# Why won't this work?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class HashingDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please input the size of the hash table: ");
        int tableSize = keyboard.nextInt();

        LinkedListN[] hashTable = new LinkedListN[tableSize];

        // this works
        LinkedListN list = new LinkedListN();
        list.addToEnd(50);
        System.out.println(list);
        //

        System.out.print("Enter the number of keys to be hashed: ");
        int numberOfKeys = keyboard.nextInt();

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfKeys; i++) {
            int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(10000) + 1;

            int location = randomNumber % tableSize;

            hashTable[location].addToEnd(randomNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

LinkedListN is a custom class, (code attached below) because arrays don't handle generics too well.

But every time I run this program I get the following error:

```
Please input the size of the hash table: 10
LinkedListN@5265a77f
Enter the number of keys to be hashed: 20
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at HashingDemo.main(HashingDemo.java:30)
```

Even though as I commented above, if I just have a single LinkedListN and add data to it, there's no issue. What's up here? I've tried and tried to figure it out, but I cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LinkedListN[] hashTable = new LinkedListN[tableSize];` just allocates the array, not the objects inside it. To overcome the `NullPointerException` you have to allocate object for each element:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfKeys; i++) {
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(10000) + 1;
    int location = randomNumber % tableSize;
    if(hashTable[location]==null) {
        hashTable[location] = new LinkedListN();
    }
    hashTable[location].addToEnd(randomNumber);
}
```

you have missed the line **`hashTable[location] = new LinkedListN();`**

Comment: Alternatively, you can check whether the `LinkedListN` is initialized in the loop (a lazy initialization), which could conserve memory in large sparse tables.

Comment: I guess I'm used to using primitives, or if objects I'm using Strings and they're automatically set to "". Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff why to check? It is definitely not initialized anywhere else (in this code atleast).

Comment: You don't want to overwrite the `LinkedListN` if it already exists. The point of the linked list is to overcome collisions in the hash.

Comment: This code is dangerous - the `new LinkedListN` line should be in an if statement, otherwise it'll delete the list every time - see irrelephant's answer below

Comment: @DougSmith: `String`s are _not_ automatically set to "".  They would be `null` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change the loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfKeys; i++) {
    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(10000) + 1;
    int location = randomNumber % tableSize;

    if(hashTable[location] == null)
        hashTable[location] = new LinkedListN();
    hashTable[location].addToEnd(randomNumber);
}
```

Otherwise the `hashTable[location]`s will be null when you first use them.